# Does flurry track by install or userId, iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, flurry

I want Flurry to track on an install basis but they include a userId attribute as well. I would prefer to put in loginIds so I can see email addresses in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

We track on the basis of device IDs, which are tracked on the basis of 1st App launch. We track new users on 1st App launch and they are tracked on the basis of 1st App launch.
Also, we will not be able to provide these device IDs.

Thanks